# Scala type inference failure on "? extends" in Java code

Tags: generics, scala, type-inference, scala-2.7

I have the following simple Java code:

```
package testj;
import java.util.*;

public class Query<T> {

    private static List<Object> l = Arrays.<Object>asList(1, "Hello", 3.0);

    private final Class<? extends T> clazz;

    public static Query<Object> newQuery() { return new Query<Object>(Object.class); }

    public Query(Class<? extends T> clazz) { this.clazz = clazz; }

    public <S extends T> Query<S> refine(Class<? extends S> clazz) {
        return new Query<S>(clazz);
    }

    public List<T> run() {
        List<T> r = new LinkedList<T>();
        for (Object o : l) {
            if (clazz.isInstance(o)) r.add(clazz.cast(o));
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

I can call this from Java as follows:

```
Query<String> sq = Query.newQuery().refine(String.class); //NOTE NO <String>
```

But if I try and do the same from Scala:

```
val sq = Query.newQuery().refine(classOf[String])
```

I get the following error:

> error: type mismatch
>   found :lang.this.class[scala.this.Predef.String]
>   required: lang.this.class[?0] forSome{   type ?0 <: ? }
>   val sq = Query.newQuery().refine(classOf[String])

This is only fixed by the insertion of the correct type parameter!

```
val sq = Query.newQuery().refine[String](classOf[String])
```

Why can't scala infer this from my argument? Note I am using **Scala 2.7**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inference works against Scala 2.8.0.Beta1.

For earlier versions, it works if you change:

```
public <S extends T> Query<S> refine(Class<? extends S> clazz)
```

to:

```
public <S extends T> Query<S> refine(Class<S> clazz)
```

`scalac -print` suggests that the interpretation of the Java signatures hasn't changed across Scala releases. So the difference is probably in the typer/inferencer itself.

### Scala 2.7.5

#### Original

```
def refine[S >: _root_.scala.Nothing <: T](clazz: Class[_$1] forSome {
  type _$1 >: Nothing <: S
}): Query[S] = _;
```

#### Modified

```
def refine[S >: _root_.scala.Nothing <: T](clazz: Class[S]): Query[S] = _;
```

### Scala 2.8.0.Beta1

#### Original

```
def refine[S >: scala.Nothing <: T](clazz: Class[_$1] forSome {
  type _$1 >: Nothing <: S
} = _): Query[S] = _;
```

#### Modified

```
def refine[S >: scala.Nothing <: T](clazz: Class[S] = _): Query[S] = _;
```

Comment: Yes - I realize that the change works, but it is unnecessarily restrictive in my opinion. For example, I should be able to say `refine[Collection](classOf[LinkedList])` or something like that